# Filling the second combo box based on the first combo box

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I want to fill the second combo box based on the first combo box.
The first combo box have these values: John, Marry, Lona, Fred

```
    A         B
1  John      384
2  John      475
3  John      450
4  Marry     616
5  Marry     526
6  Lona      569
7  Lona      234
8  Lona      937
9  Lona      477
10 Fred      286
```

For example when I choose John in combobox1, there should be these values in combobox2: 384,475,450
My code doesn't work:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_change()

Set rngItems = Sheet1.Range("B1:B10")
Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet2.ComboBox2
    For Each cel In rngItems
        If ComboBox1.Value = cel.Value Then

            oDictionary.Add cel.Value, 0
            .AddItem cel.Value
        End If
    Next cel
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as it stands isn't working because you are searching `Column B`, the column with the numeric values, for a match to the names. To fix, use the `OFFSET` function to check the cell to the left. For example:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_change()

Set rngItems = Sheet1.Range("B1:B10")
Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet2.ComboBox2
    For Each cel In rngItems
        If ComboBox1.Value = cel.Offset(,-1).Value Then

            oDictionary.Add cel.Value, 0
            .AddItem cel.Value
        End If
    Next cel
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are setting rngItems to column B.  What you want to do is set it to column A, and then get the value from column B.  Try this:

```
Set rngItems = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10") 
Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet2.ComboBox2
    For Each cel In rngItems
        If ComboBox1.Value = cel.Value Then
            oDictionary.Add Cells(cel.row, cel.column + 1).Value, 0
            .AddItem Cells(cel.row, cel.column + 1).Value            
        End If
    Next cel
End With
```

End Sub